# Converting a text file to graph

Tags: c#, dictionary, graph, text-files

I'm trying to convert a text file into a graph but when i try to print the values in the dictionary using the values function (below) it prints something like "System.Collections.Generic.List '1 [System.String]"!Can someone tell me what's wrong in my code?! [This is the format of the text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywNIi.png)

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.IO;


namespace Demo
{

public class Graph
{
    Dictionary<string, List<string>> st;
    static int count;
    static int count1;


    public Graph()
    {
        st = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
    }
    public Graph(string filename, string delimeter)
    {
        st = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

        FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open);

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);


        while(sr.Peek()!=-1)
        {
            string line = sr.ReadLine();
            char r;
            r = Convert.ToChar(delimeter);

            string [] names = line.Split(r);               

            for(int i=1;i<names.Length;i++)
            {
                addEdge(names[1], names[i]);

            }

        }

        sr.Close();
    }

    public void addEdge(string a, string b)  
    {
        if(!st.ContainsKey(a))
        {
            addVertex(a);
        }
        if(!st.ContainsKey(b))
        {
            addVertex(b);
        }
        st[a].Add(b);
        st[b].Add(a);
        count1++;   


    }

    public void addVertex(string v)
    {
        isContainV(v);
        st.Add(v, new List<string>());
        count++;
    }
    public int vertexcount()
    {
        return count;
    }
    public int edgeCount()
    {
        return count1;
    }
    public void edge()
    {
        foreach (string key in st.Keys)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(key);
        }
    }
    public void values()
    {
        foreach (List<string> temp in st.Values)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(temp);
        }
    }
    public bool isContainV(string v)
    {
        if(!st.ContainsKey(v))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    public IEnumerable<string> adjacentTo(string v)
    {
        return st[v];
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't write a collection of strings, you need to add another loop to write each string.

```
    foreach (List<string> temp in st.Value)
    {
       foreach (string s in temp)
       {
          Console.WriteLine(s);
       }
    }
```

If you want to just have one loop for the whole Dictionary try this...

```
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> entry in st)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(entry.Key);

       foreach (string s in entry.Value)
       {
           Console.WriteLine(s);
       }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! I have a question though is it possible to loop on each keyvalue pair if I were to make a function that prints the whole dictionary?